# Corda: how drain node works for scheduled states

Tags: corda

I am going through corda [docs](https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-node.html#draining-mode) about draining nodes and following line from it makes me suspicious

> Scheduled flows due will be ignored.

Does it mean that in draining mode, scheduled flows wil not run, but once the node is drained, upgraded and undrained - will they start again?

How would it work if during upgrade some states/flows were upgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If draining mode is enabled on the node, scheduled flows are suspended. The flows would resume once draining mode has been disabled i.e. any flow whose scheduled time falls in the past once the draining is disabled would start to execute.

Comment: Hello Ashutosh! I have the same understanding, but my question is how to perform state upgrades if some flows will be resumed.  Is not the purpose of draining node to ensure that no flows are resumed?

Comment: No, purpose of draining is to make sure that the node clears all current task and doesn't take up new task as it get ready for an upgrade. The consuquences post upgrade has to be handled in the upgraded cordapp.

Comment: If you are doing an explicit upgrade, the scheduled stated are consumed which means your new states produced should now return a scheduled activity which would run at the time specified in them, for implicit upgrade the states must now be compatible so that there is no issue.